# Creating a multiple sided shape using GeneralPath and lang.Math(GUI) in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, math, geom

I want to create a shape with mulitple sides using Lang.Math and GeneralPath in Java GUI. I was able to transfer the value of ne(the number of sides) from Fenster to my class but the code isnt working. ik the code for the shape is right because it was same code i used for hexagon.
i think the problem might be that the number sides is in variable form(because if i change the variable with a number it seems to work) but idk how to fix it.
it is showing the following error
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
at Neck.genneck(Neck.java:30)
at Zeichnung.paintComponent(Zeichnung.java:104)"
Please help me

**this is the code **

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;

public class Neck extends Form {
    int r;
    private int ne ;
    private double[] px, py;
    
    

    public Neck(int x, int y, int r) {
        super(x,y);
        this.r=r;
        px=new double[ne];
        py=new double[ne];


    }
    
    public void seiten (int ne) {
        this.ne=ne;
    }
    

    public Shape genneck() {
        for(int i = 0; i<ne; i++) {
             
            px[i]=x+(r*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i*360/ne)));
            py[i]=y-(r*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i*360/ne)));
        }


        GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_NON_ZERO);
        path.moveTo(px[0],py[0]);
        for(int i = 1; i<ne; i++) {
            path.lineTo(px[i],py[i]);
        }
        path.closePath();
        return path;
    }

   }
```

Comment: Do some debugging. In the for loop, print out the values held by your array. Are they as expected?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels it is not letting me debug it , it is showing that the problem lies at line
      px[i]=x+(r*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i*360/ne)));

Comment: What do you mean "it's saying..."?  does it not compile? If so, your question should show the error message

Comment: Does your super class have private fields for x and y? If so you'll need to change them to protected or else call a getter method. Regardless, please ask a more complete question

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry I meant it is not compiling and showing error, and no the x and y fields are protected and they work with other shapes I coded.

Comment: and my question is what can i do to fix it

Comment: Edit your question and show the compiler's error message. Again, it is very important

Comment: Is the problem "cannot find symbol" due to not importing Shape? Best not for us to guess though. Please show us the message

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter this was the error message(the first 3 lines the error message was very long)
**Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
 at Neck.genneck(Neck.java:30)
 at Zeichnung.paintComponent(Zeichnung.java:104)**

(Zeichnung is the class where I export the shape to)

Comment: took me a while but the naming is in German, right? 'Neck'  is for n-Eck (a polygon with n sides), 'seiten' to set the number of sides. (Not that it makes any difference for the problem, but often helps me to understand the goal and the problems reaching it)

Answer (score 0):

To stop the compiler complaining, I had to provide this `Form` class:

```java
public class Form {
    protected int x;
    protected int y;
    protected Form(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Also an import was missing in your code:

```java
import java.awt.Shape;
```

The problem with your `ne` variable is that it is not initialized in the constructor, so the default will be `0`, and your `px` and `py` arrays will always be of length 0. Also the method `seiten` is problematic, because you will modify the length for the loop but not recreate the arrays `px` and `py`, so it will for sure raise an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in the `genneck` method.

To solve this you should

- initialize the field `ne`, either with another constructor parameter like you do it for `x`, `y` and `r` or with a sensible default (maybe `3` for a triangle?). Do the initialization of `ne` *before* you initialize `px` and `py`.
- re-initialize `px` and `py` whenever you give `ne` another value (so in the method `seiten`)

In general I would recommend that you just add a constructor parameter and remove the `seiten` method completely, if possible, it makes things more complicated.

Additionally I would recommend that you remove the unnecessary import:

```java
import java.swing.*;
```

You also should split the declarations of `px` and `py` for better readability, and make the `360` in the calculations of `px` and `py` into explicit `double` values (`360.0`) to ensure that the division does not result in an integer and is casted then (this will let you loose all digits after the decimal separator):

```java
px[i] = x + (r * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i * 360.0 / ne)));
py[i] = y - (r * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i * 360.0 / ne)));
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation and you were right the error was "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length )" but can you please help me fix it.

Comment: I added some hints how to fix it, but please do me a favour and add the exception and a description to your question.